# Windows Docker - reNgine

Tags: docker

I tried running the project [reNgine](https://rengine.wiki/usage/) in a docker container. When pulling the repo and running `docker compose up` I get the following error:

```
------
 > [celery internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/ubuntu:20.04:
------
failed to solve: DeadlineExceeded: DeadlineExceeded: DeadlineExceeded: ubuntu:20.04: failed to authorize: DeadlineExceeded: failed to fetch oauth token: Post "https://auth.docker.io/token": dial tcp 3.216.34.172:443: i/o timeout
```

Does someone know the cause? I did try to logout and login again, setting `"buildkit": false` and pulling the Ubuntu image (V. 20.04) separately, which worked fine. Nothing helped so far.